# Can't seem to create an interface to satisfy TypeScript getting missing property

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to create an interface to make `TypeScript` happy.
I am doing:

```
@Output() onChange:IMyEvent<ISliderItemData> = new Subject().delay(300).debounceTime(1000) ;// emits ISliderItemData
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error:(68, 5) TS2322:Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'IMyEvent<ISliderItemData>'.
  Property '__isAsync' is missing in type 'Observable<{}>'.
```

I tried to satisfy TS with the following code but it did not work:

```
class IMyEvent<T> extends Subject<T> {
    __isAsync: boolean;
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use `Subject<ISliderItemData>`? What's the point of `IMyEvent`?

Comment: ya that's the first thing I tried and getting ```Error:(68, 5) TS2322:Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Subject<ISliderItemData>'.
  Property 'observers' is missing in type 'Observable<{}>'.``` odd I know :/

Comment: Ah because after the debounce and the delay you don't have a subject, you have an observable. Those should instead be on whatever subscription is going to push events onto the output, which can then just be an `EventEmitter` of `ISliderItemData`. .

Comment: That's the odd thing, I am casting it as Subject, which satisfied both an Observer and Observable, but TS not happy ...

Comment: Yes, because it's **not** both an observer and an observable at the moment; it's *just an observable*. Could you give the context of this event in the rest of the class? I think you're jut putting the delay in the wrong place.

Comment: I see, I can cast it as Observable which FIXES the problem, but later I can't call next as it doesn't exist ```this.onChange.next({
            to: to,
            direction: direction
        })```

Comment: I can do something nasty like ``` this.onChange['next']({
            to: to,
            direction: direction
        }) ``` I guess :/

Comment: or better I guess ``` (this.onChange as Subject<ISliderItemData>).next({
            to: to,             direction: direction        }) ```

Comment: You can't call next on it, because it doesn't have that method. That's my point; *it is just an observable*, those methods you're chaining on it take away its observer status. They should be moved out to whatever is observing the events, or in to whatever's pushing them to the output in the first place.

Comment: got it tx!!!! appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I did not test it but I would guess following might work:

`@Output() onChange:IMyEvent<ISliderItemData> = <IMyEvent<ISliderItemData>>(new Subject().delay(300).debounceTime(1000)) ;`

Why you don't define folloowing?

```
class IMyEvent<T> extends Observable<T> {
    __isAsync: boolean;
}
```

and then using:
`@Output() onChange:IMyEvent<ISliderItemData> = new IMyEvent<ISliderItemData>().delay(300).debounceTime(1000) ;`

That would create typed Subject (and be converted to Observable by delay() and debounceTime())

**Edit:**
I have changed original answer - `Subject` to `IMyEvent`. On top - if I see the code and comments - I believe it would be better to keep clean `Subject` to be able to call `next()` as you need and use `delay()` and `debounceTime()` on consuming side.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem because they actually *want* the subject, they want to call `.next` on it.

Comment: correct, same issue ```Error:(70, 5) TS2322:Type 'Subject<ISliderItemData>' is not assignable to type 'IMyEvent<ISliderItemData>'.
  Property '__isAsync' is missing in type 'Subject<ISliderItemData>'.```

Comment: Yes, see my **edit** - Issue is caused by mixing of `Observer` and `Observable` roles. On top - `EventEmitter` currently extends `Subject`, so usage of `Subject` works. But if implementation of `EventEmitter` would be changed to something else, then using something else than `EventEmitter` might complicate future upgrades of application.

Answer (score 0):

So as @jonrsharpe said, you can do it on the push side, but if you want to do it at declaration, this will work:

```
@Output() onChange:Observable<ISliderItemData> = new Subject().delay(300).debounceTime(1000);
```

...

and later:

```
 (this.onChange as Subject<ISliderItemData>).next({data})
```

Answer (score 0):

As you indicated,

```
@Output() onChange:IMyEvent<ISliderItemData> = new Subject().delay(300).debounceTime(1000) ;// emits ISliderItemData
```

You are taking a Subject and then calling the delay operator on it. At that point, you no longer have a Subject - you instead have an Observable. Any further operators chained onto that will also return Observables. Therefore, the result of your expression (i.e. the stuff on the right of the '=') is an Observable. Hence, Typescript expects your declaration on the right to be of a matching type i.e. an Observable.

So, the simplest form of this would be:

```
@Output() onChange: Observable = new Subject().delay(300).debounceTime(1000) ;// emits ISliderItemData
```

However, in your case, you want to type your onChange variable to indicate what type the Observable emits. You should also type your Subject so that it matches. So, this becomes:

```
@Output() onChange: Observable<ISliderItemData> = new Subject<ISliderItemData>().delay(300).debounceTime(1000) ;// emits ISliderItemData
```

The reality is that Typescript is pretty smart about inferring types based on usage, so you could actually use:

```
@Output() onChange = new Subject<ISliderItemData>().delay(300).debounceTime(1000) ;// emits ISliderItemData
```

The Typescript compiler will see that the return type of your delay operator (and resulting debounceTime operator) is Observable and automatically assign that type to your onChange instance variable.

It's personal preference in this case whether you bother to put the type on the onChange variable - it's not needed by the compiler but can be useful to add some code clarity.